# Configuring a Server to redirecting?

Tags: redirect, redirection

Assume my server domain is `www.dl2.com`
I wanna to configure it for redirecting each request to another server without showing the link of destination server. 
e.g:
There is a download link in my web page in `www.dl2.com`, I wanna when a user click on the link, the server redirect it to `www.dl.com\sth\sth.exe`. but I don't wanna the user see the second link.
How can I do it?

Comment: to answer this question you need to provide more information. What server OS are you using?

Comment: @Fergus: I wanna use Apache Server on Linux and IIS on Win Server.

Answer (score 1):

if you use apache web server you can use the ProxyPass directive part of the proxy module.

something like this into your config will do

```
ProxyPass /sth/sth.exe http://www.dl.com/sth/sth.exe
ProxyPassReverse /sth/sth.exe http://www.dl.com/sth/sth.exe
```